# What type of charts are used by Google Cloud -> Compute Engine -> OBSERVABILITY?

Tags: charts, google-compute-engine

I am trying to implement charts similar to the ones I see on Google Cloud's Computer engine page, when you navigate to the "OBSERVABILITY" tab.

[image]

I tried to find some hints by inspecting it but only noticed `ac-chart` tags used but no library info.

Does anyone know what library this is?
My initial guess was `Google charts` or `HightCharts JS` but I cannot confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Google chart is using their own libraries along with the corechart package for plotting the charts in the GCP console.  These charts are free and can be used by anyone, go through the [google charts developer page](https://developers.google.com/chart) for more information on how to load these libraries. This is the example script for loading the google charts

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script>
  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  ...
</script>
```

Comment: @Brian is this post helped you in understanding about google charts..? if you have any other queries revert back...